# System of equations. Find values for A.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

*Find the values of the parameter a for which the system has (1) one solution, (2) no solutions, and (3) infinitely many solutions. In case (3), find the solution.*

I'm so sorry about the picture, but I need extra help with it. Hope you understand me.

Probably my attempt is not true, can someone help me how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: *a=-7/3, when i was finding a for no solutions

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your handwriting correctly, it looks like you are studying the system $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ where
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 2 & a + 3 \\
2 & 3 & a + 4 \\
3 & 6 \, a + 5 & 7
\end{array}\right] & \vec{b} &= \left[\begin{array}{r}
8 \\
12 \\
20
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
The determinant of $A$ is
$$
\det(A)=-15 \, a + 1
$$
So, our system is guaranteed a unique solution if and only if $a\neq\frac{1}{15}$.

If $a=\frac{1}{15}$, then our system can be reduced to
$$
\operatorname{rref}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 & 2 & \frac{46}{15} & 8 \\
2 & 3 & \frac{61}{15} & 12 \\
3 & \frac{27}{5} & 7 & 20
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & \frac{8}{15} & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
What does this reduction tell us about the solvability of the system in this case?

Comment: Sorry, it is 1 not 2, in the first equation for X. (1,2,a+3). And i found determinant right, i checked it here. https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=7fcb0a2c0f0f41d9f4454ac2d8ed7ad6